# cannot parse VideoView.setVideoURI

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm try to make VideoView as below.

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.1429313800506));
```

but it shows Syntax error on token ".1429313800506", delete this token.

I don't know what's wrong in that syntax;
1429313800506.3gp is located in /res/raw/

It didn't get problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1429313800506` is not a valid java identifier. Variables have to start with a `letter` the `_` or `$`, and since the content of res/ is translated in java identifiers at compile time, you have to rename the file's name to be compliant to the java conventions/rules

Answer (score 2):

**`Capital letters,Numbers and some symbols`** are not allowed to be in the name of the file .You should use ***small letter*** instead `1429313800506`